# Fluent Nhibernate: Cant delete an item with as HasMany property

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I dont normally deal with data like this but I thought id give it a try. As it turned out I failed :/ and am not sure how to proceed.

I have a database object track:

```
public virtual string Type { get; set; }

public virtual IList<DateTypeTrack> TrackDates { get; set; }
```

With a mapping file:

```
Table("Tracks");
Map(x => x.Type).Not.Nullable();
HasMany(x => x.TrackDates).KeyColumn("TrackID").Cascade.All();
```

The DateTypeTrack Object looks like this:

```
public virtual DateType DateType { get; set; }
public virtual Track Track { get; set; }
public virtual int Days { get; set; }
```

With a mapping file like this:

```
Table("DateTypeTracks");
References(x => x.DateType, "DateTypeID").Not.Nullable();
References(x => x.Track, "TrackID").Not.Nullable();
Map(x => x.Days).Not.Nullable();
```

If its necessary, Ill post the DateType code aswell, but I dont think its needed.

And am trying to write a delete method in my service layer that is pretty simple:

```
public void PushDelete(int id)
    {
        Track track = _tracks.Get(id);

        try
        {
            _tracks.BeginTransaction();
            _tracks.Delete(track);
            _tracks.CommitTransaction();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _tracks.RollbackTransaction();
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I keep getting an error:

```
could not delete collection: [TSE.Domain.DatabaseObjects.Track.TrackDates#12][SQL: UPDATE DateTypeTracks SET TrackID = null WHERE TrackID = @p0]
```

I dont know why its trying to do the update at the end, but I suppose that is what is causing the issue. What sort of recourse do I have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the `DateTypeTrack` already cares for the association between the two entities you should mark the HasMany as `Inverse` to tell NH that the hasmany does not maintain it (the Update)

```
HasMany(x => x.TrackDates).KeyColumn("TrackID").Cascade.All().Inverse();
```

Comment: So, should I delete the items before I delete the main object?

Comment: no, cascade all will cascade the delete command to the items. no need to do it manually